# Maintaining formatting (newline char) when removing stopwords (NLTK)

Tags: python, nltk

I'm using NLTK to remove stopwords from a file. The file is a series of tweets delimited by newline char. I've it set up to remove stop words but its also stripping out the newline characters and so it's no longer one tweet per line. Here's my code:

```
stuff = codecs.open("/Users/user/Desktop/ngrms/Nonsrcstic.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8")
word_list = stuff.readlines()
[x.encode('utf-8') for x in word_list]

f = open('english')
stops = f.read()

for line in word_list:
    for w in line.split('\n'):
        if w.lower() not in stops:
            with open("nostops_Nonsrcstic.txt", "a") as tweetsNoStops:
                tweetsNoStops.write(w.encode('utf-8') + " ")
```

Input file looks like this:

```
 Baby boomers are now at the age where "work or retire" is frequently considered choice. 
 There's a few people I miss but the truth of the matter is, my name probably hasn't crossed their minds or they don't give a shit about me 
 What you must remember is, I do yarn shows with the help of a Fiat Panda and Tatiana, the trailer, which is small #itfitsbehindaPanda  
 @BetBright The AP boost won't work lads says try again later is there a problem with the site?
```

Output looks like this:

```
Baby boomers age "work retire" frequently considered choice.  There's people miss truth matter is, name probably hasn't crossed minds don't give shit must remember is, yarn shows help Fiat Panda Tatiana, trailer, small #itfitsbehindaPanda @BetBright AP boost won't work lads says try later problem site?
```

Comment: Your `split` removes the '\n', you'll have to write it back out explicitly after the `for w in line.split` loop. Put `tweets.NoStops.write(w.encode('utf-8') + "\n")` at the same indent level as the `for w` loop.

Comment: You have be a little more specific about what you're asking for us to help you better. What exactly is the question?

Comment: Try to consider the newlines while splitting, may be not taking the input in this way.